# Migration source question keeps redirecting me to the migration destination

Tags: support, status-bydesign, migration

I was the last person to vote to migrate a post on SU, which was migrated to https://serverfault.com/questions/650576/getting-pcs-to-report-to-wsus

The browser automatically forwarded me to the new post, on the SF site.

I cannot return back to SU via the back button in my browser (despite the back button being enabled). I also have no idea why I was forwarded to this new location? I've only voting, I don't need to see it's moved as if I need it verified :)

Is this just me experiencing this?

**Edit**

(as per @Robotnik's comment) If I right click the back button, I can see the history. In order it shows current page (SF), the previous page (is the original SU post (which I guess becomes a forwarder)), and then previous is the review queue...  So when I hit back, I'm reaching a forwarder... All makes sense.

Either way, I was not taken to a revision page! I was forwarded.

**EDIT**

It happened again today (15th Jan 2015). I closed a question on SU, which was migrated to WebApps . If I hit back, it redirects me to the webapps page. Screen shot of the history (right click on back button)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't clicking on the migrated from... link take you to revisions page from SU?

Comment: This didn't happen for me when I voted to migrate http://superuser.com/questions/850352/whats-the-difference-between-remove-windowsfeature-and-uninstall-windowsfeature?noredirect=1

Comment: Pressing 'back' you're probably being redirected to the question's page on SU... which is now set up to redirect you to SF. Try right-clicking the back button (or clicking the 'back' history dropdown) and navigate to the page (or the page before that) manually.

Comment: @Robotnik, yes, via the history I can navigate back 2 pages!

Comment: @Sathya, no. I never saw a revisions page. I kept getting (what I assume) a forwarder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sathya pointed out, the "migrated from superuser.com" status block has a link back to [the revisions](https://superuser.com/posts/850483/revisions) - this is done so that deleted questions can still be viewed.

However, that revisions page's link to its parent question page doesn't have the redirect-preventing query parameter:

```
https://superuser.com/questions/850483/getting-pcs-to-report-to-wsus?noredirect=1
```

I'm not sure if we need to add it to the revisions page, though.

Comment: As an aside - only moderators don't get auto-redirected.  OUR POWER KNOWS NO BOUNDS! :)

Comment: he he, well, I see. So, it is by design we're forwarded to the new page? I assume this also occurs if we close a post for being a dupe and we're forwarded to the dupe page? As always, thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: And either way, I was not returned to the 'revision page'. Every time I hit back, or via the history clicked on the previous page, I was redirected to the SF page. However, it appears as if it's just me (using Firefox Dev Edition)

Comment: Yeah, if you were just hitting your browser's back button, you'd continue to be redirected to Server Fault; you would have needed to click the "migrated from..." link on the Server Fault question to go back to Super User.  Maybe after a closure occurs, we should just add the `noredirect=1` query parameter on the closing site.

Comment: Hi @Jarrod, it's happened again today.